# How to replace variable with an existing const value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace a variable from a URL string with an existing const array value but I keep returning an empty object. For example, if animalURL = Dogs3, then newAnimal should replace Dogs3 with Dog

```
const animal = {
  "Dogs3": "Dog",
  "cat1": "Cats",
  "Fish2": "Fish",
};

var newAnimal = document.getElementById("newAnimal").href;
var animalURL = newAnimal.split("/")[3];

let newAnimal = animalURL.replace(animalURL, animal);

var animalBtn = document.createElement("div");
animalBtn.setAttribute("id", "animalBtn");

document.body.appendChild(animalBtn);
document.getElementById("animalBtn").innerHTML = newAmimal;
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code as well?

Comment: Simple doubt? Is it possible to use `let newAnimal` after declaring `var newAnimal = document.getElementById("newAnimal").href;`

Comment: @RinshanKolayil Nope.

Comment: @RinshanKolayil absolutely not.

Comment: @I_love_vegetables Just wanted to get the jist of the problem and not give a vague solution to the problem.

Comment: `String.prototype.replace` does not work that way

Comment: @I_love_vegetables A [mre] is always appreciated so that answers can be tested for correctness immediately, on the site, without the need to create a test harness.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ah yeah agreed, its not really necessary in this case but it will be nice to have them so it will be easier for us to help. Im taking back my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the character, what you need to do is fetch the value from the `animal` object after you split the URL and get the endpoint inside the variable `animalURL`.

Replaced the `.replace()` method with the below code and the endpoints can be changed easily.

`let newAnimal = animalObj[animalEndPoint];`

Also please try to give meaningful names to the variables, which would help in increasing the code readability.

```js
const animalObj = {
  "Dogs3": "Dog",
  "cat1": "Cats",
  "Fish2": "Fish",
};

var animalURL = document.getElementById("newAnimal").href;
var animalEndPoint = animalURL.split("/")[3];

let newAnimal = animalObj[animalEndPoint];

var animalBtn = document.createElement("div");
animalBtn.setAttribute("id", "animalBtn");

document.body.appendChild(animalBtn);
document.getElementById("animalBtn").innerHTML = newAnimal;
```

```html
<a id='newAnimal' href='/Dogs3' />
```

Comment: Thanks Jateen, and noted regarding the naming.

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace()` is return new string (result from replaced string), example :

```js
const name = "foo";
name.replace('o', 'a');
// 'faa'
```

from your case, you replace a char from a string with an object, it same like you add a string with an object, when this happened the object will be converted into a string it will returned as `[object Object]`

```js
const name = 'foo';
name + {};
// 'foo[object Object]'

// your case
name.replace(name, {});
// [object Object]
// 
// you replaced your string with an object, and the object be converted into a string
```

Try this one :

```js
const animal = {
  "Dogs3": "Dog",
  "cat1": "Cats",
  "Fish2": "Fish",
};

var newAnimal = document.getElementById("newAnimal").href;
var animalURL = newAnimal.split("/")[3];

// removed let, that is illegal to redeclare the newAnimal variable
newAnimal = animal[animalURL];

var animalBtn = document.createElement("div");
animalBtn.setAttribute("id", "animalBtn");

document.body.appendChild(animalBtn);
document.getElementById("animalBtn").innerHTML = newAnimal;
```

Comment: Answers with "Try this" followed by more code are rarely helpful. Instead, add an explanation of what code you added or removed and how that solves the issue.